# Is there a way to flatten a .pdf image from the command line?

Tags: bash, pdf, image-manipulation, gimp

In GIMP, I can import a PDF, and use the GUI to flatten it (if it was made with many layers) by selecting `Flatten Image` in the `Image` dropdown menu.  I can then export the PDF with a new filename.

I would like to automate this.  Is there some way to do it via the terminal?

Comment: install imagemagick and read man mogrify-im6 , montage-im6 , display-im6 , stream-im6 , identify-im6 , import-im6 , conjure-im6, composite-im6 , convert-im6 , animate-im6 and compare-im6 .

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found these 2 method via Google, in this thread titled: [Re: Flattening PDF Files at the UNIX Command Line](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Support/talk_archives/2011/0681.html).

*Method #1 - using Imagemagick's convert:*

```
$ convert -density 300 orig.pdf flattened.pdf
```

**NOTE:** The quality is reported to be so so with this approach.

*Method #2 - Using pdf2ps -> ps2pdf:*

```
$ pdf2ps orig.pdf - | ps2pdf - flattened.pdf
```

**NOTE:** This method is reported to retain the image quality.

Comment: Better quality than GIMP on the second -- thanks!

Comment: @ACD - that's good to know. Glad it solved your Q.

Comment: Method 1 generated a very fuzzy image, while method 2 worked perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately, Method #2 does not rasterize the image, so if you are trying to block out sensitive portions, a user could still open the document and remove layers (with something like Inkscape).

You can, however, modify the resolution of Method #1:
`$ convert -density 150 {original,flattened}.pdf`

If you need to preserve disk space, you can use `-type Grayscale` or `-monochrome` or things of that sort.

Comment: Both methods will rasterize the pdf, although the method #2 does it at a much higher resolution. So none of these methods are satisfying.

Comment: Regarding Method #1, also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605006/convert-pdf-to-image-with-high-resolution

Comment: I'm using this for resizing notes. Method 2 took ages to convert 12 pages from 2 MB to 70 MB (pdf->ps) and back (ps -> pdf). Ghostscript did it faster.

Comment: When I run the `convert` command I get an error. My PDF is only text, no images.  error: ```convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
convert: no images defined `no_protect_raster.pdf' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3285.```

Comment: The second method increase the size of my PDF more than 10x, and lost text highlighting annotation created with Evince.

Answer (score 24):

Ghostscript (gs) worked better than `pdf2ps` and `convert` for me. Quality was hardly degraded and file size is small.

```shell
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-sColorConversionStrategy=/LeaveColorUnchanged  \
-dAutoFilterColorImages=true \
-dAutoFilterGrayImages=true \
-dDownsampleMonoImages=true \
-dDownsampleGrayImages=true \
-dDownsampleColorImages=true \
-sOutputFile=document_flat.pdf document_original.pdf
```

Found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220527115602/http://zeroset.mnim.org/2015/01/07/flatten-pdfs-with-ghostscript/). Note the comment about removing the `/` before `LeaveColorUnchanged`.

Comment: This method works great, the pdf is not rasterized and text is conserved as text

Comment: I tried using this to remove a transparency layer via flattening, but it did not work for me.

Comment: It changed a font for me but otherwise much better resolution than the other proposed methods.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with batch files in place?

Comment: This did not work for me, I get "Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops". The ps2pdf solution above did work.

Comment: Got also "Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops". The ghostscript-answer from user107769 did work.

Comment: To fix the `Unrecoverable error: rangecheck in .putdeviceprops` remove the forward slash (`/`) before LeaveColorUnchanged.

Comment: How would we do this if the image is greyscale?  (ie. no need for color.)

Comment: @Diagon `-sColorConversionStrategy=Gray` (haven't tried it)

Answer (score 13):

ghostscript changed their default for flattening annotations in late 2016.

To simply flatten a PDF now, you need `-dPreserveAnnots=false`

So a simple command line is now

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
-dPreserveAnnots=false \
-sOutputFile=document_flat.pdf document_original.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, worked well for me. This command seems to give the same output as Stan Bondi's answer while being simpler. Both were much quicker and gave a smaller file than using `convert`.

Comment: Ya, ditto.  Worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Although convert will keep the same file size I've found it to be slow.

The pdf2ps ps2pdf method is faster but I noticed for me it was increasing the file size.

pdftk is nice because it is not only fast but also retains a similar file size.

This is what I use to bulk flatten a directory.

```
    function pdfflatten () {
        pdftk "$1" output "$2" flatten
    }
    export pdfflatten
    alias pdfflattenDIR='mkdir flattenedPDFs; for i in `seq $(ls *.pdf | wc -l)`; do a=`ls *.pdf | head -$i | tail -1`; pdfflatten "$a" flattenedPDFs/"$a"; done'
```

Comment: pdftk flatten does _not_ change the images within a PDF. From the docs it "merges an input PDF’s interactive form fields (and their data) with the PDF’s pages"

Comment: To be clear, this approach doesn't flatten transparent layers (as indicated above).

Comment: This works awesome

Answer (score 0):

I frequently need to flatten PDFs or make them image-only. I wanted to do this quickly from within Nautilus instead of going to a terminal, so I created two [Nautilus scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) based on the previous answers. I am sharing the instructions in case they are useful to others.

**Create script to flatten PDFs:**

1. Go to the Nautilus script folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`
2. Create a new shell script file (eg `FlattenPDF.sh`)
3. Make this file executable (eg Natiuls `Properties` → `Permissions` → `Allow executing file as program`)
4. Insert below text into the file:

`#!/bin/bash`

```
# Flattend PDFs    

IFS='
'
for file in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    base=${file%.*}
    ext=${file##*.}
    newname=${base}_flat.pdf
    gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPreserveAnnots=false -sOutputFile=$newname $file
  fi
done
```

**Create script to create image-only (text not searchable or selectable) PDFs:**

1. Go to the Nautilus script folder `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`
2. Create a new shell script file (eg `ImageOnlyPDF.sh`)
3. Make this file executable (eg Natiuls `Properties` → `Permissions` → `Allow executing file as program`)
4. Insert below text into the file:

`#!/bin/bash`

```
# Image-only PDFs    

IFS='
'
for file in $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
do
  if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    base=${file%.*}
    ext=${file##*.}
    newname=${base}_img.pdf
    gconvert -density 200 $file $newname
  fi
done
```

Restart nautilus (eg type `nautilus -q` to quit Nautilus and then open Nautilus from the Dash again). If you right-click on a file, you should see the `Scripts` menu with the new scripts.

Answer (score 0):

The `pdf2ps` and `ps2pdf` method did not compress my file. So I invented my own way:

> libreoffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /tmp/ input.pdf

You should see a factor of 5 reduction in space in the output file:

> ls -lah /tmp/input.pdf

I tested it in CentOS 7 and 9 computers.