# Flatten transparency in PDF to remove thin white lines?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, poppler

I have a PDF created with Quark Xpress where some raster images are shown with thin white lines across them. Searching around I have found that the problem is due to the way PDFs readers apply partial transparencies, see http://indesignsecrets.com/when-you-see-thin-white-lines-in-your-pdf-files.php.

The suggested solution is to either 1) turning off the "Smooth images" setting in Acrobat Reader or 2) ignore the problem because it will print just fine. Solution 1 requires efforts from the readers and is thus not practicable. Solution 2 is also not applicable to my case because these PDFs will be mostly (or only) be seen on monitors and not printed.

I tried to flatten the images using the answers given to question [Is there a way to flatten a .pdf image from the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162922/is-there-a-way-to-flatten-a-pdf-image-from-the-command-line) but to no avail:

- the `convert` method removes the white lines but converts all the text into a big raster image;
- the `pdf2ps | ps2pdf` and `gv` methods do not remove the white lines (I suppose that `poppler` and `gv` have a switch equivalent to the "Smooth images" setting of Acrobat Reader, but I could not find it).

How can I post-process the PDFs so that the parts with raster images are flattened and no white lines appear any more?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this @gioele? we are facing the same difficulty.